# Check to see if any Input elements are in focus

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I have a jquery script that displays a div when any key on the keyboard is pressed. I'd like to add a condition to the script that will only run the script if no other input area (textarea or texfields) are in focus on the page. That way you can actually type on the rest  of the page without showing the div.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (!$('#test').is(':visible')) {
        //######## IF (every input is not active....) {
        if (65 <= e.keyCode && e.keyCode <= 90) {
            $(elem).fadeIn();
            $('#textarea').val('');
            $('#textarea').focus();
            $('#textarea').val(temp);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks. I can give every other textarea on the page the same ID if that is necessary.

Comment: BTW you can't "give the same ID" - duplicated IDs are invalid HTML and your JS/jQuery will only catch the first element.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use jQuery's [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) pseudoselector

```
if ( $('input:focus').length > 0 ) {  return; }
```

Or for your code example

```
if ( $('input:focus').length == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Yes, agreed. But I think for new developers it explicitly points out what is going on. Thanks for fixing my code errors.

Comment: No problem, just added that as a side note - I personally prefer the shorter conditions `if ($('input:focus').length)` and `if (!$('input:focus').length)` which take less characters to type and read, plus all developers have to learn how to deal with truthy and falsy values at some point. But yes, it is mostly personal preference only. `=]`

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Thanks so much. I was afraid I'd have to specify each text field on the page which would be really redundant. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery's `.is()` and `document.activeElement` like this.

```
var targetInput = $('#myInput');

if(!targetInput.is(document.activeElement)) {
    alert('Typed while not focused on #myInput!');
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXhQM/)**

Comment: +1 but remember that [this is HTML5 only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.activeElement).

Comment: @JosephSilber what? It says IE4 support. *confused*

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Me too. **This attribute is part of the in-development HTML 5 specification.**

Comment: @JosephSilber being that Internet Explorer is the main target when HTML 5 is an issue, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533065(v=vs.85).aspx it's supported by IE 5+ so I don't see this being an issue, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I believe other browsers may already have supported it for a good time and it has been standardized by the W3C in HTML5 only?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Good to know. The table at the bottom of that MDN page seems to concur, so I don't really know what *in-development* means.

Comment: @JosephSilber I believe it is because the W3C draft didn't reach the Recommendation stage yet, the MDN link to the [W3C Specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#focus-management) was last updated 2 days ago. No wait, it says "Living standard" now I'm even more confused.

Comment: @JosephSilber Guess I've been a little late on the news, but now WHATWG works on a Living Standard version of HTML, which is kind of split from the W3C. See http://html5doctor.com/html5-living-standard/ Oh and more directly to what matters: [What does "Living Standard" mean?](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_does_.22Living_Standard.22_mean.3F) which explains the "in development" part.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery, all you have to do is search for input or textarea elements that are currently in focus.

```
if ( $('input:focus, textarea:focus').length === 0 ) {
    // put some code here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend using this for any form inputs

```
if ( $(':input:focus').length ) { ... }
```