# Not execute a function if any input is on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, onfocus

I'm searching a way not to execute a function(e) if any input of the page is on focus.
I tryed several ways unsuccesfully ;(

Here is my code :

```
document.onkeyup=function(e){

  var e = e || window.event;//Pour IE   

  // Action sur la barre d'espace (32)
  if(e.which == 32) {
    $("#play").click(); 
    return false;
  }

   //Action sur entrée (13)
  if(e.which == 13) {
    $("#play").click(); 
    return false;
  }

}
```

I tryed something like this

```
if ($('input').is(":focus")) {
}
else{ my code }
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you for helping me !

Etienne

Answer (score 1):

onfocus Event in javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)">

<p>When the input field gets focus, a function is triggered which changes the background-color.</p>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
    x.style.background = "yellow";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Saniya, but I would prefer to detect if any input is on focus, and then not to execute the function if it is the case using if...else.
So a better question would be "how to detect if any input is on focus ?" Do you have any idea how I can get this ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to the reformulation of my question, it was already asked in another thread of stackoverflow : [Check to see if any Input elements are in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431762/check-to-see-if-any-input-elements-are-in-focus).

So, adapted to my code here it is :

```
  document.onkeyup=function(e){

  var e = e || window.event;//Pour IE  

  if ( $('input:focus').length > 0 ) {}
  else{     // if an input is not focused, the function is executed

      // Space bar action (32)
      if(e.which == 32) {
        $("#play").click(); 
        return false;
      } 
       //Enter key action (13)
      if(e.which == 13) {
        $("#play").click(); 
        return false;
      }
    }
 }
```